# How to hide bottom view of tabbar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm using Custom tabbar with following code:

```
UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HomeDB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HomeLB.png"];    
UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ScheduleDB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ScheduleLB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BuildingsDB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BuildingsLB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"InformationDB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"InformationLB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MoreDB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MoreLB.png"];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;

tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage3];
[item4 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage4 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage4];
```

My problem is when customize tabbar, there still have a view (which I set color to red) at the bottom of tabbar. Look like this:

[image: http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2868/9668334491_eb3e39d001_b.jpg]

Is there anyway to remove it without hidding default tabbar and replace it with a custom view?
 I've check it in Stackoverflow, in UITabbar reference but still find no way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, replace your custom tabBar:

```
- (void)oppoHideTabBarViewController
    {
        if (self.tabBarViewController.tabBar.hidden == YES)
        {
            return;
        }

        UIView *contentView;

        if ( [[self.tabBarViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]] )
        {
            contentView = [self.tabBarViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
        }
        else
        {
            contentView = [self.tabBarViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        contentView.frame = CGRectMake(contentView.bounds.origin.x,
                                       contentView.bounds.origin.y,
                                       contentView.bounds.size.width,
                                       contentView.bounds.size.height + self.tabBarViewController.tabBar.frame.size.height);

        self.tabBarViewController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

    }

    - (void)oppoShowTabBarViewController
    {
        if (self.tabBarViewController.tabBar.hidden == NO)
        {
            return;
        }

        UIView *contentView;

        if ([[self.tabBarViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            contentView = [self.tabBarViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
        }
        else
        {
            contentView = [self.tabBarViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        contentView.frame = CGRectMake(contentView.bounds.origin.x,
                                       contentView.bounds.origin.y,
                                       contentView.bounds.size.width,
                                       contentView.bounds.size.height - self.tabBarViewController.tabBar.frame.size.height);

        self.tabBarViewController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You try:

```
- (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{   
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBarclass]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y + 36, view.frame.size.width, 480 - 36)];
        }
    }
}
```